# Reparameterizing non-linear functions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, modeling, nonlinear-regression

Consider the Ricker function:
$$
 y = axe^{-bx}
$$

Where the maximum fitted value of $y$ can be obtained as follows:
$$
y_{max} = \dfrac{a}{b}e^{-1}
$$
and the value of $x$ at $y_{max}$ can be obtained as follows:

$$
 x_{max} = \dfrac{1}{b}
$$

I wish to reparameterize the Ricker function so that $y_{max}$ and $x_{max}$ are included in non-linear least-squares optimization. Basically, $y_{max}$ and $x_{max}$ are of importance to my research question, and I would like to optimize the model fit for these parameters.

I am not a mathematician and am unaware of if this is challenging or simple task.

You help is much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "add these terms to the Ricker function"? Are you talking about reparameterizing the function from being in terms of $(a,b)$ to expressing it in terms of $(y_\text{max},x_\text{max})$?

Comment: Hi Glen_b, yes that is correct. Reparameterizing is the objective.

Comment: Plug in the algebraic identities $a=ey_\text{max}/x_\text{max}$ and $b=1/x_\text{max}$.

Comment: Hi whuber, excellent thank you! Quite straight forward. I should have known to do this.

Comment: @Patrick perhaps you could put that in as an answer (I doubt whuber will do it for this question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

whuber has answered this question with:

> Plug in the algebraic identities $a=ey_{max}/x_{max}$ and
>   $b=1/x_{max}$

This results in

$$y = {y_{max}}/{x_{max}} \,\cdot\, e^{-{x}/{x_{max}}+1}$$